# Can Cordova play WebM video format on iOS?

Tags: ios, cordova, video, webm

I use some MP4 video in my Cordova App, but for saving many place, can I play WebM video format in an iOS app created with Cordova ?

Thanks for you idea :)

Environnement :
Cordova 5.1.1
Xcode 7.2
iOS 8 / 9

Comment: No, not really, unless you want to go after a hardcore plugin, stick to mp4

Comment: Ok, seems there is many plugins for cordova.
Is there an hardcore WebM plugin for cordova ?